# Crop without deleting cropped pixels? - Photoshop ExtendScript

Tags: photoshop-script

When you use the crop tool there is a check box labeled, "Delete Cropped Pixels."

[image]

If you script a crop, it deletes cropped pixels. How do you disable it?

I would have expected a boolean argument but that isn't the case:
[image]

Comment: A lot of options aren't available through DOM in Photoshop, unfortunately. You could record a code for this tool in ActionManager format using a Scripting Listener plugin: and change the option there.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy, do you have any advice how to get the Scripting Listener to work? It seems to be deprecated or something, as the documentation isn't reflective of where you actually find it, and installing it results in an error:
"One or more plug-ins are currently not availabel on your system."

Comment: I'd make sure that you're installing a correct version? I'm using it without issues both on Windows and Mac

Comment: System info shows the following:

Plug-ins that failed to load:

   ScriptListener NO VERSION -  - from the file “C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2020\Plug-ins\Scripting Utilities\ScriptListener.8li”

Comment: don't know if it makes any difference but it should be located in `Adobe Photoshop 2020\Plug-ins\ScriptListener.8li`

Comment: I'll try that. That might be more outdated documentation that had me put it in that folder.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy, I moved it to the location you indicated, but I get the same error. Do you know the proper place to actually get the latest version of the plug-in, in case mine is bad?

Comment: I just re-downloaded it from this page: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html, and followed the instructions, which resulted in no error, but no plugin found. I then put it back where I originally had it, and now it works. Weird. Yay! Thanks for your help @SergeyKritskiy

Comment: Ugh! Glad to hear it works now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of the ScriptingListener code wrapped in a function with the option for Delete Cropped Pixels:

```js
crop({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  right: 300,
  bottom: 300,
  deleteCropped: false
});

function crop(data)
{
  if (data.deleteCropped == undefined) data.deleteCropped = true; // default value

  var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
  var descRectangle = new ActionDescriptor();
  descRectangle.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID('Top '), charIDToTypeID('#Pxl'), data.top);
  descRectangle.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID('Left'), charIDToTypeID('#Pxl'), data.left);
  descRectangle.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID('Btom'), charIDToTypeID('#Pxl'), data.bottom);
  descRectangle.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID('Rght'), charIDToTypeID('#Pxl'), data.right);
  desc.putObject(charIDToTypeID('T   '), charIDToTypeID('Rctn'), descRectangle);
  desc.putUnitDouble( charIDToTypeID('Angl'), charIDToTypeID('#Ang'), 0.000000 );
  desc.putBoolean(charIDToTypeID('Dlt '), data.deleteCropped);
  executeAction(charIDToTypeID('Crop'), desc, DialogModes.NO);
} // end of crop()
```

Comment: How would I crop based on a selection? (Ie, I don't know the "left" "top" etc as you have defined.

Comment: Use `activeDocument.selection.bounds` to get the selection coords

Comment: Works perfectly - too bad Adobe didn't bother to document the deleteCropped parameter, woulda been helpful!  >:@

Comment: @Adam the documened DOM contains only maybe a third of available PS commands and options. While code generated by ScriptingListener may seem weird and unreadable with experience it's quite forward to change and read

Comment: Funny that I never thought about using the ScriptingListener simply to see all the undocumented options of a particular function. Good idea.